# In the case of the Ricci flow, the symmetries of the flow are scalings and diffeomorphisms

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Can anyone help me and prove that **in the case of the Ricci flow, the symmetries of the flow are scalings and diffeomorphisms**?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "symmetry"?